# Set options in ghci

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use string interpolations like here http://hackage.haskell.org/package/interpolate-0.2.0/docs/Data-String-Interpolate.html

Specifically,

```
>>> :set -XQuasiQuotes
>>> import Data.String.Interpolate

>>> let name = "Marvin"
>>> putStrLn [i|name: #{name}|]
name: Marvin
```

If I run this in ghci it works fine. Also if i write  a file like shown here, this also works https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.3/docs/html/users_guide/ch04s02.html

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XQuasiQuotes #-}
import Data.String.Interpolate

main = do
  let name = "Marvin"
  putStrLn [i|name: #{name}|]
```

But if I just use the options and import in the file, and run the commands in ghci i get an error `parse error on input'#'`

```
-- in file example.hs
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -XQuasiQuotes #-}    
import Data.String.Interpolate

-- in GHCi, ghci example.hs, then run
> let name = "Marvin"
> putStrLn [i|name: #{name}|]
`parse error on input'#'`

what's happening here and why can't i run the command in ghci?
thanks
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Language features enabled in the individual modules don't propagate to `ghci` session. You have to re-enable them, i.e. do `:set -XQuasiQuotes`.

---

By the way, you should enable language features using

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
```

syntax in the Haskell source files.